# Append a php array with a key/value that is setup in another file

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to append an array by adding a key/value that is not part of the same file.

For example I have this array:

```
$div_size = array(

    'Accordion' => array(
        'element1-4'=>'1/4',
        'element1-3'=>'1/3',
        'element1-2'=>'1/2',
        'element2-3'=>'2/3',
        'element3-4'=>'3/4',
        'element1-1'=>'1/1'
     ),
);
```

I need to add this:

```
    'blog' => array(
        'element1-4'=>'1/4',
        'element1-3'=>'1/3',
        'element1-2'=>'1/2',
        'element2-3'=>'2/3',
        'element3-4'=>'3/4',
        'element1-1'=>'1/1'
     ),
```

$div_size = array() is in file foo.php and the appended key/value 'Accordion' => array() is in file bar.php

The result of the two actions must be:

```
$div_size = array(

    'Accordion' => array(
        'element1-4'=>'1/4',
        'element1-3'=>'1/3',
        'element1-2'=>'1/2',
        'element2-3'=>'2/3',
        'element3-4'=>'3/4',
        'element1-1'=>'1/1'
     ),

    'blog' => array(
        'element1-4'=>'1/4',
        'element1-3'=>'1/3',
        'element1-2'=>'1/2',
        'element2-3'=>'2/3',
        'element3-4'=>'3/4',
        'element1-1'=>'1/1'
     ),
);
```

What I am trying to do is add an additional option in the admin section of my Wordpress parent theme but the additional array value needs come from the functions.php file in my child theme.

Comment: use [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the commenters...here is what I did to get this to work.

In the child Wordpress theme I created a file like this or you can add it to your functions.php file.

```
// path to the parent theme with the array you want appended
include TEMPLATEPATH . '/whatever/some-file.php';

// the key/value you want appended
$div_size_merge = array(
    'blog' => array(
      'element1-4'=>'1/4',
      'element1-3'=>'1/3',
      'element1-2'=>'1/2',
      'element2-3'=>'2/3',
      'element3-4'=>'3/4',
      'element1-1'=>'1/1'
   ),
);

// now merge the two    
$div_size = array_merge($div_size, $div_size_merge);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_merge()`

```
$div_size = array_merge($div_size, $other_array)
```

Comment: For this to work dosen't $div_size need to be a global variable? The appended key/value is coming from a different file so how will $div_size be known?

Comment: You need to include that other file: `include(...)` or `require(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The child theme's function.php is loaded right before the parent theme. So a function should be set. See WP info: [Using functions.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php)

Declare and implement a function in your child theme's functions that creates the needed array. Call it something unique. Say `THEMENAME_getBlogArray()`

Check for the function being set using `if ( function_exists('THEMENAME_getBlogArray()')`. If it's set, use it. In your case

```
$other_array = THEME_getBlogArray();
$div_size = array_merge($div_size, $other_array)
```

should do the trick. (If you need you can validate it after you call the function.)

Hope this helps.